# TortoiseSVN svnserve.exe error 1053, will not start

Tags: svn, windows-services, tortoisesvn, svnserve

I am trying to install svnserve.exe as a service from the TortoiseSVN kit.

```
TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi
```

Creating the service appears correct, but it will never start. I have seen many messages about getting the quoting correct on the `binpath` parameter. I think this is correct.

If I try to start the service in the Windows services GUI, error 1053 is reported.

Any suggestions?

```
C:>svn --version
svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)
   compiled Dec 13 2015, 15:47:16 on x86-microsoft-windows

C:>sc create svnserve ^
More?   binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service --log-file C:\repos\svn.log -r C:\repos" ^
More?   displayname= "Subversion" ^
More?   depend= tcpip ^
More?   start= auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

11:06:21.28  C:\Users\pwatson
C:>net start svnserve
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the log file and repo directory were on D: and not C: drives. When that was finally identified and corrected, it seems to be working as expected.

Does anyone know where information leading to a more direct problem identification could be found? I did not see anything in the Windows Event Viewer.